Biber on Mac does not work
I am trying to get used to latex and used Biber for references. I used Texmaker and changed the default to Biber as well. I found here a simple code which I attached below.  It works for the example file but when I replaced it with my own bib file and reference it did not work. I even tried another application called texstudio but it is not working as well. What could be the problem? Any help will be appreciated.
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{bir.bib}
\bibliography{bir.bib}
%\bibliographystyle{apacite}


\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
}

%% ##############################
\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\citep{hp2017}.
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum~\citet{hp2017}.
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}

bib file:
@article{hp2017,
   author = {RJ Hodrick and EC Prescott - Journal of Money and undefined credit and and Banking and undefined 1997},
   journal = {JSTORRJ Hodrick, EC PrescottJournal of Money, credit, and Banking, 1997•JSTOR},
   title = {Postwar US business cycles: an empirical investigation},
   url = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/2953682?casa_token=90RmOxzlQ8kAAAAA:g5vcqQYfLcRS2AG8q-bW3Xc6oYJChzub-rx42qnAh7fv9BHIjChI0yfMduS0ySdcfF42HV7BLxaDPMn_lMylRdSP7Hu-eyNNTwmwOIQaG_mP5A5QCQM},
}


If it works with the example file, but not your bib file, might it be that there is a problem in the bib file, which you don't show us?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

texmaker and texstudio are just the editors used to write your source files they are not directly related to the typesetting they just call latex or biber in the background

In what way does it not work?  Are you doing the full pdflatex, biber, pdflatex, pdflatex?  Do you get error messages?

I mean it does not give any error code. but instead of the citation itself, pdf shows citation key: hp2017. I created the bib file from Mendeley. It contains only one reference to try out. I am attaching the bib.file content in the original post. Thanks for the comments.

The syntax of the author files is wrong. The journal name shouldn't be in the author field.

Use something like author = {Robert J. Hodrick and Edward C. Prescott},

The syntax of the author field is wrong. The journal title etc. shouldn't be part of the author field:
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

% downloaded from https://www.jstor.org/stable/2953682?origin=crossref
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{hp2017,
 ISSN = {00222879, 15384616},
 URL = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2953682},
 abstract = {We propose a procedure for representing a time series as the sum of a smoothly varying trend component and a cyclical component. We document the nature of the comovements of the cyclical components of a variety of macroeconomic time series. We find that these comovements are very different than the corresponding comovements of the slowly varying trend components.},
 author = {Robert J. Hodrick and Edward C. Prescott},
 journal = {Journal of Money, Credit and Banking},
 number = {1},
 pages = {1--16},
 publisher = {[Wiley, Ohio State University Press]},
 title = {Postwar U.S. Business Cycles: An Empirical Investigation},
 urldate = {2024-08-12},
 volume = {29},
 year = {1997}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
}



%% ##############################
\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\citep{hp2017}.
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum~\citet{hp2017}.
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}



Thank you very much! A final question. Why do you think it appears ibid in stead of year?

using ibid instead of repeating the citation is a choice of your style. You can switch this off or use another style.

The entry in the bib file is malformed. If I process with LaTeX and Biber the following file
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{hp2017,
   author = {RJ Hodrick and EC Prescott - Journal of Money and undefined credit and and Banking and undefined 1997},
   journal = {JSTORRJ Hodrick, EC PrescottJournal of Money, credit, and Banking, 1997•JSTOR},
   title = {Postwar US business cycles: an empirical investigation},
   url = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/2953682?casa_token=90RmOxzlQ8kAAAAA:g5vcqQYfLcRS2AG8q-bW3Xc6oYJChzub-rx42qnAh7fv9BHIjChI0yfMduS0ySdcfF42HV7BLxaDPMn_lMylRdSP7Hu-eyNNTwmwOIQaG_mP5A5QCQM},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
}

%% ##############################
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\citep{hp2017}.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum~\citet{hp2017}.

\printbibliography 

\end{document}

I get on the console, during the run of Biber,
WARN - Name in key 'hp2017' is empty (probably consecutive 'and'): skipping entry 'hp2017'
WARN - Entry with key 'hp2017' in section '0' is cited and found but not created (likely due to sourcemap)

Of course, whatever comes in the author field after Prescott should be removed and also the journal field should be fixed and the year field filled. Ensure to get BibTeX data from knowledgeable sources.
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{hp2017,
   author = {R. J. Hodrick and E. C. Prescott},
   journal = {Journal of Money, credit, and Banking},
   year={1997},
   title = {Postwar {US} business cycles: an empirical investigation},
   url = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/2953682?casa_token=90RmOxzlQ8kAAAAA:g5vcqQYfLcRS2AG8q-bW3Xc6oYJChzub-rx42qnAh7fv9BHIjChI0yfMduS0ySdcfF42HV7BLxaDPMn_lMylRdSP7Hu-eyNNTwmwOIQaG_mP5A5QCQM},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=green!70!red,
}

%% ##############################
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\citep{hp2017}.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum~\citet{hp2017}.

\printbibliography 

\end{document}


